# method for defining 2D/3D dimensions directly?

Tags: sketchup, cad

I'm just getting into Google SketchUp, and I'm already annoyed with the way rectangles are drawn and the Pull/Push tool works.

I wanted to make a 2000x1000x100mm shape, but ended up with something like 1998.3x1002.7x99.1mm. That was the closest I could get.

I found this mouse-based expansion *really* irritating, considering I knew the exact dimensions I wanted.

Is there a way to just define new objects numerically?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes!

Simply start pulling, making or doing whatever you want - do it in the right direction and after you release the mouse, before you do anything else, just type a number and press <kbd>enter</kbd>.

For example, if you want to extrude in one direction, pull out any distance, then just type <kbd>1</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>0</kbd>, <kbd>enter</kbd>. This will then extrude 100 (units you selected at project start) in the direction you pulled.... You can use a negative number to go in the opposite direction from the one you selected.

Comment: move mouse a bit, type numbers, hit enter -- works perfectly, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

To really make sure your dimensions are exactly what you want,

- choose the rectangle tool
- click on the screen (usually at 0,0,0 or where ever you want your box to start)
- after you click, move your mouse. You should see at the bottom of your screen a Dimensions bar with numbers that change as your mouse moves.
- all you need to do at this point is type in your dimesions (so 2000, 1000 - just the x & y) and hit enter
- a rectangle will appear so at this point you simply use your push/pull tool.
- click the face of the rectangle, move your mouse upwards, and type in your z-dimension
- hit enter and you are done!

  This can also be done with circles - just note the dimension is the radius by default